# Why did Soyuz TMA-18M take two days to reach the ISS?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, soyuz-spacecraft, transfer-time

Typically, a Soyuz crew vehicle takes 4 orbits to reach the [ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station), but the [Soyuz TMA-18M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TMA-18M) took 34 orbits or 2 days to reach it. Why is there so much variation from typical missions?

Comment: It's a tradeoff between delta/v, duration, and timing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually, a roughly 2-day rendezvous is *standard**, and the 4-orbit *expedited rendezvous*, while being practiced more in the recent years, also involves phasing the International Space Station's orbit so it precisely coincides with the launch site at precise time (thus the *instantaneous launch window*), which sometimes isn't possible.

This Soyuz TMA-18M rendezvous was one of those latter cases, because the station had to do [Pre-determined Debris Avoidance Maneuvers in July 2015](https://blogs.nasa.gov/stationreport/2015/07/27/), and also slight phasing corrections for the next week's Soyuz TMA-16M landing, which set it out of phase for the *expedited rendezvous* with Soyuz TMA-18M. Since it was already out of phase, it also performed an [orbital reboost on August 31](https://blogs.nasa.gov/stationreport/2015/08/31/iss-daily-summary-report-083115/), just two days before the TMA-18M launch. An additional reboost will be performed on September 7, to finalize setup for TMA-16M landing and next uncrewed Progress 61P launch to the station on October 1.

---

*I said in the beginning that the 2-day rendezvous is *standard*, so I should also mention that failing to perform *expedited rendezvous* for any reason, one of the fallback procedures is the switch to 2-day rendezvous. So 2-day rendezvous mode is always an option with crewed Soyuz launches, while the *expedited rendezvous* not necessarily. Thus *standard*.

Comment: I read somewhere that astronauts prefer the 2-day trip. During the 4 orbit trip they just sit down.

Comment: I imagine after the end of the second day I'd be pretty ready to get out of that can.

Answer (score 8):

The fast approach mission is relatively rare, and has only been done recently. According to this [news article](http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2015/09/soyuz-tma-18m-one-expedition-crewmember-iss/):

> Soyuz TMA-18M was to be tasked with achieving a fast-track, six-hour rendezvous with the ISS. However, that approach was cancelled due to the current altitude of the Station.
>
> To achieve such a fast-track docking, Soyuz TMA-18M would have had to perform the first two pre-programmed engine burns during its very first orbit of Earth.

Comment: ...and we all know that the first orbit's SOP is packed with tests of the ship's systems ===