# Just how record-setting was the launch-to-docking time of the April-4-2019 Progress resupply mission?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, docking, progress

Digital Trend's article [3-plus-hour supply trip from Earth to International Space Station breaks record](https://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/iss-resupply-record-trip/) mentions that this was even faster than the typical "fast-track" Russian launch-to-docking time for a resupply mission.

It links to astronaut Nick Hague's [tweet](https://twitter.com/AstroHague/status/1113973472844238850):

> A visitor arrived at @Space_Station today...the progress resupply vehicle made record timing as it launched and docked to the station in under three and a half hours. Pretty impressive!

Was this *substantially* faster than the previous ones, or is it a new record by only a few minutes?

If substantial, what was done differently to make it so fast?

See also:

- [Why did Soyuz TMA-18M take two days to reach the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10882/12102)
- [How did Soyuz MS-04 reach the ISS in only 6 hours?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21819/12102)
- [Soyuz TMA-18M ISS rendezvous: expedited 4-orbit vs regular 34-orbit - How does fuel usage compare?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10891/12102)

Comment: The keywords you are looking for are expedited rendezvous

Comment: @Antzi I've added links to some of the most relevant items, thanks!